# Installing skype in Slackware x86_64

Tags: linux, 64-bit, skype, slackware

I'm trying to install skype in my Slackware 14.1 x86_64, but I'm don't a super user in this system so I need some help.

When I start in command line the output is...

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The multilib suport is installed.
And this lib is installed in my system.

ldd output:

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xffffe000)
        libXv.so.1 => not found
        libXss.so.1 => not found
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf53cc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf53c7000)
        libX11.so.6 => not found
        libXext.so.6 => not found
        libQtDBus.so.4 => not found
        libQtWebKit.so.4 => not found
        libQtXml.so.4 => not found
        libQtGui.so.4 => not found
        libQtNetwork.so.4 => not found
        libQtCore.so.4 => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf53ab000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf52c3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf5280000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf5266000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf50db000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf771d000)
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that without root access you won't be able to install the missing packages to make that work.
If you can get root access you should be able to find the packages you need here: http://pkgs.org/
Make sure to pick the packages for your operating system and version.
It's been a while since I ran Slackware but I think the install command goes like `slackpkg -install <name of package>`
You need to do this AS ROOT.  You might also need to do a google search to make sure you know which package contains which libraries.
Another correct syntax is listed on that site (there's more than one way to do it), so if it's different to what I've said use that instead of mine.

Comment: If I don't find the tgz/txg package, can I download the rpm (for example) and convert them?